# Can't build appcompat on Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle

Every time I start a new project on Android Studio I have this problem. It's starting to piss me off.

Here is my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.estudiotrilha.inevent"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.21.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.45'
}
```

As expected, since I'm using `appcompatv21`, I need to build it using build tools 21+.

When I build, I get more than 400 errors, all looking like these:

```
/Users/mauricio/AndroidstudioProjects/InEvent/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3/res/values/values.xml
Error:(609, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowFixedHeightMajor'.
Error:(596, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowFixedHeightMinor'.
Error:(590, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowFixedWidthMajor'.
```

Here is my `styles.xml` file. Maybe it helps to solve the problem.

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:inevent="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.estudiotrilha.view"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <style name="Floating" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>      
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    </style>    

    <style name="Transparent" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>      
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NoActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>      
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Header">
        <item name="android:textColor">#0c5890</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Header2">
        <item name="android:textColor">#0c5890</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    </style>

    <!-- DARK ACTIONBAR -->
    <style name="DarkActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/backgroundDark</item>
        <item name="background">@color/backgroundDark</item>

        <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/TextColorDarkActionBar</item>
    </style>    

    <style name="SpinnerTextAppearenceDarkActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DropDownItem.Spinner">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextColorSpinnerDarkActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextColorSpinnerDarkActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Base.DropDownItem.Spinner">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/textLight</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextColorDarkActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/textLight</item>
    </style>
    <!-- END -->

    <!-- PURPLE ACTIONBAR -->
    <style name="PurpleActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/backgroundPurple</item>
        <item name="background">@color/backgroundPurple</item>

        <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/TextColorDarkActionBar</item>
    </style>
    <!-- END -->

    <!-- WHITE ACTIONBAR -->
    <style name="WhiteActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:background">@color/background</item>
        <item name="background">@color/background</item>

        <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/TextColorWhiteActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextColorWhiteActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text</item>
    </style>
    <!-- END -->

    <style name="InEventTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/WhiteActionBar</item>

        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/text</item>

        <item name="setAcceptIcon">@drawable/ic_action_accept</item>
        <item name="setAddIcon">@drawable/ic_action_new</item>
        <item name="setCancelIcon">@drawable/ic_action_cancel</item>
        <item name="setEditIcon">@drawable/ic_action_edit</item>
        <item name="setFeedbackIcon">@drawable/ic_action_half_important</item>
        <item name="setMessageIcon">@drawable/ic_action_new_email</item>
        <item name="setNewEventIcon">@drawable/ic_action_new_event</item>
        <item name="setPresenceIcon">@drawable/ic_action_cc_bcc</item>
        <item name="setQuestionIcon">@drawable/ic_action_help</item>
        <item name="setRefreshIcon">@drawable/ic_action_refresh</item>
        <item name="setRemoveIcon">@drawable/ic_action_discard</item>
        <item name="setShareIcon">@drawable/ic_action_share</item>
    </style>

    <style name="WlPilatesTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/DarkActionBar</item>

        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/textLight</item>
        <item name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerTextAppearenceDarkActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerTextAppearenceDarkActionBar</item>

        <item name="setAcceptIcon">@drawable/ic_action_accept_light</item>
        <item name="setAddIcon">@drawable/ic_action_new_light</item>
        <item name="setCancelIcon">@drawable/ic_action_cancel_light</item>
        <item name="setEditIcon">@drawable/ic_action_edit_light</item>
        <item name="setFeedbackIcon">@drawable/ic_action_half_important_light</item>
        <item name="setMessageIcon">@drawable/ic_action_new_email_light</item>
        <item name="setNewEventIcon">@drawable/ic_action_new_event_light</item>
        <item name="setPresenceIcon">@drawable/ic_action_cc_bcc_light</item>
        <item name="setQuestionIcon">@drawable/ic_action_help_light</item>
        <item name="setRefreshIcon">@drawable/ic_action_refresh_light</item>
        <item name="setRemoveIcon">@drawable/ic_action_discard_light</item>
        <item name="setShareIcon">@drawable/ic_action_share_light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="StartupABCTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle" tools:ignore="NewApi">@style/PurpleActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/PurpleActionBar</item>

        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/textLight</item>
        <item name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerTextAppearenceDarkActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerTextAppearenceDarkActionBar</item>

        <item name="setAcceptIcon">@drawable/ic_action_accept_light</item>
        <item name="setAddIcon">@drawable/ic_action_new_light</item>
        <item name="setCancelIcon">@drawable/ic_action_cancel_light</item>
        <item name="setEditIcon">@drawable/ic_action_edit_light</item>
        <item name="setFeedbackIcon">@drawable/ic_action_half_important_light</item>
        <item name="setMessageIcon">@drawable/ic_action_new_email_light</item>
        <item name="setNewEventIcon">@drawable/ic_action_new_event_light</item>
        <item name="setPresenceIcon">@drawable/ic_action_cc_bcc_light</item>
        <item name="setQuestionIcon">@drawable/ic_action_help_light</item>
        <item name="setRefreshIcon">@drawable/ic_action_refresh_light</item>
        <item name="setRemoveIcon">@drawable/ic_action_discard_light</item>
        <item name="setShareIcon">@drawable/ic_action_share_light</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I don't know what to do anymore, I'm following every instruction, and it still fails to build. PS: when I use appcompatv20 it also throws a lot of errors.

Why is so harsh to use appcompat with Android Studio? This is the only library that I always waste time trying to build it.

Comment: That's rather odd. The lines in question are *defining* these attributes, if I am reading the XML correctly. Try bumping your `buildToolsVersion` to `21.1.2` (the current version), installing it from the SDK Manager if you do not have it already. If that does not help, grab [any of my AppCompat samples](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AppCompat) and see if you can build it. If you can, then your problem is tied to your project (interference from one of the other dependencies?).

Comment: @CommonsWare I reset the entire project and started copying code step from step to find the problem. The problem start to happen when I copy my styles.xml. I'll edit the post with my styles.xml file.

Comment: @CommonsWare This project works on Eclipse. I'm trying to move from eclipse to android studio.

Comment: @CommonsWare When I start a new project it works fine. The problem is when I try to copy the code that works on Eclipse to Android Studio.